# Помогите поменять иконки при hover

Tags: javascript, css3, html5

```css
.header-left-title
 color: #ffffff
 font-family: "Open Sans"
 font-size: 18px
 font-weight: 700
 display: block
 text-align: center
 letter-spacing: 0.5px
 margin-top: 10px
.header-list
 display: -webkit-flex
 display: -moz-flex
 display: -ms-flex
 display: -o-flex
 display: flex
 justify-content: center
 padding-left: 0
 list-style-type: none
 margin: 0
 &__item
  margin-left: 30px
  &:first-child
   margin-left: 0
  i
   font-size: 40px
```

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
    <span class="header-left-title">вступить в наши группы</span>
    <ul class="header-list">
        <li class="header-list__item">
            <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="header-list__item">
            <i class="fab fa-telegram"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="header-list__item">
            <i class="fab fa-vk"></i>
        </li>
        <li class="header-list__item">
            <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[image]

А НАДО СДЕЛАТЬ ТАК:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну дак и сделайте их картинками, а не шрифтом, и замените их в `:hover`

Comment: ну или эффект ч/б сделайте для обычных, и убрать его для ховера

Comment: А можно увидеть код пожалуйста ?

Comment: @user312259, див, внутри 2 дива, в одном текст, в другом куча спанов или имг-тегов с определенными классами. классам задаете бг и при ховере меняете чтото, что вам нужно (тень, цвет, размер (вы не указали в вопросе)). дерзайте.

Comment: ок, спасибо, а все же код показать лучше :))